# TypeError, got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

Прохожу гайд из книжки по фреймворку Джанго. Книга 2017 года, но уже есть некоторые различия по версиям, которые в ходе реализации проекта дают о себе знать, но это всё в целом решается.
В руководстве дошло до авторизации пользователей. Собственно, предлагается такой код:

*Urls.py:*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

from . import views

app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

Исправляю django.contrib.auth.views, убирая "views". Сервер запускается и я получаю ответ:

> TypeError at /users/login/
>
> login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'

Просматриваю способы решения проблемы в интернете, натыкаюсь на возможность поменять импорт и сам путь на следующее:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

Уже на это я получаю следующую ошибку:

> TypeError at /users/login/
>
> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

И здесь у меня ступор и я не могу разобраться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, от чего мне отталкиваться в разрешении ситуации?

Comment: C django я почти не работал, но сейчас вот полистал документацию - может быть, вам нужно вместо LoginView использовать LoginView.as_view ? У него как раз есть аргумент template_name.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое! Натолкнул ответ на правильное решение. Импортировал "from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views" и "from django.urls import path", после чего поменял путь на:
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),

Answer (score 0):

Наткнулся на такую же проблему. Нашел в интернете такой вариант и мне помогло:

```py
'''Определяет схемы URL для пользователей'''
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns=[
    #Страница входа
    path('login/',LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
]
```